# servicio en Symfony tenga como dependencia el servicio de Logger de Symfony

Tags: symfony

Estoy haciendo entrevistas para programación con el framwork de Symfony, tengo conocimientos del framwork pero mi experiencia real en proyectos reales se limita a un proyecto bastante simple en mi empresa.
Al hacer una entrevista de trabajo en la parte técnica había una pregunta que me dejo en blanco que decía:

**Define un servicio en Symfony llamado foo (utiliza el namespace que quieras para la clase Foo) que tenga como dependencia el servicio de Logger de Symfony, y que no se instancie hasta que no se utilice.**

La verdad que sigo sin entender lo que pedía, la deje en blanco pero ahora tengo la duda de como implementar ese servicio tal como especifican, ¿alguna idea?.

GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1):

Estoy casi seguro que en Symfony5 cuando creas un servicio y le pasas como argumento a éste la dependencia del servicio o de la interfaz automáticamente lo instancia gracias al inyector de dependencias

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProductController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/products")
     */
    public function list(LoggerInterface $logger): Response
    {
    /**                     ^^^^
     * Justo aquí es donde se instancia la dependencia
     */
        $logger->info('Look, I just used a service!');

        // ...
    }
```

Te recomiendo investigar acá en [Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services)